# What is the proper way to sort in elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch with a ruby application via Tire gem.
Here is my index

```
mapping do
  indexes :title
  indexes :views_count, type: 'integer'
  indexes :created_time, type: 'date'
end
```

And my query:-

```
News.tire.search load: true do 
  query {all}
  sort { by :views_count, 'desc'}
end
```

This is pretty good and looks it will be works well. However, There is unexpected result. It treats numbers as strings. That means it will consider '33' less than '4'. I want to tell elasticsearch to treat them as integers not strings.

And the same thing is happening with `created_time` but I did not notice the pattern it sorts with. I think I should pass type or something. So, any body can help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post the mapping of the index that is being created by your Ruby script. This can be achieved by `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index_name`

Comment: Thank you man. You solved it!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I only updated the index not the mapping of the index as the mapping were exist before I found out the type parameter in creating the mapping.